# Database Count & Group By error

Tags: mysql, sql, database, count, group-by

I am quite new on SQL and I am trying to practice to improve myself.

I have a database which has a

Table : Players, Teams, Plays, and Wins

Players : pid, pname, age, country

Plays   : pid, season, tid, value  ( pid -> pid in Players, tid -> tid in Teams )

Teams   : tid, tname, tcolor, tbudget

Wins    : wtid, ltid, season, wscore, lscore ( wtid,ltid -> tid in Teams )

---

The question is `Find the name of the players whose played in atleast 2 dif. teams with same color`

What I did is

```
SELECT DISTINCT P.pname 
FROM Players P
    ,Teams T1 
GROUP BY T1.tcolor
HAVING 1 < (
   SELECT COUNT (10)
   FROM Teams T2
   WHERE T1.tcolor=T2.tcolor)
```

When I try to query this , I get an error which is ;

```
Error Code: 1630
FUNCTION PRALATEST.COUNT does not exist. Check the 'Function Name Parsing and Resolution' section in the Reference Manual
```

In which part am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
select pname
from Players
join Plays on Plays.pid = Players.pid
join Teams on Teams.tid = Plays.tid
group by pname, tcolor
having count(Teams.tname) > 1
```

The condition `count(Teams.tname) > 1` is in a having clause instead of a where clause becuase it needs to operate on the results AFTER the group by is performed.

Comment: Thank you very much, in general, do I need to count something after the whole execution or depends on situation?

Answer (score 1):

Couple things.  Your error message is because you put a numeric constant in the `COUNT` function.  You should just use an asterisk.

Also, you have not specified a join condition for your `Players` and `Teams` tables.  As a result, you are doing a product join (probably not what you want). I'm guessing you need to join to your `Plays` table.

You should change your coding practice to use "explicit" join syntax to avoid errors like this in the future.